# Installing kali-linux installer amd64.iso on virtualbox

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I have a course which requires installation of virtualbox and Debian 64 packages. I downloaded kali-linux-2020.3.iso. After starting the machine for installation it stopped with a message:

```
Install the base system.Unable to install busybox 
An error was returned while trying to install the busybox package onto the target system.
Check /var/log/syslog or see virtual console 4 for the details.
```

This is not live or other version of kali-linux. It is the free download with virtualbox. Can someone help?

Comment: It is probably easier and you can get more help, if you download a Debian iso file and install Debian itself.

Comment: What host system are you using?

Comment: I am using Fedora 34 in virtualbox. I get a message when trying to install .iso file that the setting is wrong: Virtualization setting is on. I tried to correct that through reading VirtualBox Oracle forum and followed step by step code on the site: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=35892#p160750. I still got the wrong page. The disk is not supported.

Comment: I want to build a virtualbox in Fedora34 which is in virtualbox. Yet, I am missing something?